# How to see the crash reason in Eclipse debugger

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

Following this Android tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html I added two lines which should cause null pointer exception:

```
Object o = null;
o.toString();
```

Now I set breakpoint on the second line and start debugger. When debugger breaks, I click "Step over" and application crashes. However, I don't see any useful information in the debugger. Debug window shows ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity, Source window shows "No source found". I don't see any information about exception, null pointer, etc. in any Eclipse debugger window, and don't see anything pointing to my line of code that causes crash. So, what am I missing?

**Edit**. Maybe Android UI framework has its own exception handling mechanizm, which prevents me to see exception immediately in my code? Something like this happens in another UI frameworks, like WinForms, Qt, wxWidgets.

Answer (score 3):

After exception occurs you should check Logcat window for details: there you find the entire stack leading to the line of code where exception is. In some cases exception will occur in some other class (not yours) - then you should look for your package/class name in the stack to find otu whether you're "responsible" for it.

Corresponding output will not appear in Logcat immediately - let it run for some time (or until it crashes).

Also you can set "Java exception breakpoint" so the execution will break whenever there is an exception.

Comment: Please give me more details about setting "Java exception breakpoint", maybe this is what I am looking for.

Comment: Go to Run | Add Java exception breakpoint. There you can set either specific exception(s) to break on or all of them. [from eclipse .org](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fbreakpoints%2Fref-addexception_viewaction.htm)

Comment: Thanks, "Java exception breakpoint" is useful information and can help when I know unhandled exception type.

Comment: do you see any traces from your app in Logact?

Comment: Yes, I can see my own log messages.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the error in the LogCat. `Window->Show View->other->Logcat`

Comment: There is nothing new in LogCat window when I execute o.ToString line.

Comment: You are not able to see anything in Logcat?

Comment: LogCat window is working, but no new information is added to it when I execute this line.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this...

```
try {
    Object o = null;
    o.toString();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

...and use the DDMS perspective in  eclipse.

Ideally you want to catch specific exceptions so the `catch` block would be...

```
catch (NullPointerException npe {
    npe.printStackTrace();
}
```

...but doing a 'catch all' for `Exception` as in my first example and using the eclipse DDMS perspective to view logcat output will give you a good head start.

Comment: Thanks, I know about exception handling, but here I want to learn about working with unhandled exception in debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found useful information in the "Breakpoints" debugger window. It shows NullPointerException and points exactly to offensive line.